# Can I run another computers hard drive as a virtual machine

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, external-hard-drive

Last year I bought a new Windows 10 Dell Laptop which was a great machine.  After having it for about 1 month, one night I accidentally spilt some lime cordial into the side of it.  Whats strange about it was that I wiped it down and everything seemed ok that night.  The next morning however the laptop would not power up.

As I had been working on some source code for a presentation I had to remove the harddrive and plug it into another machine to get at my source code.

My problem however, was I had some software installed on it that I couldn't just copy onto a new machine and so my question is can I run this hard drive as a virtual machine from another PC?

If so what steps would I have to take and what software would I use to do it?

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. But the steps to do so are very complex and prone to errors. That makes this question too broad for SuperUser. Just installing a virtual machine and mounting the harddrive is not enough. Windows will not boot from it, which creates the actual problem. There is lots of risk for dataloss due to what is required to make it work.

Comment: There are also Windows license issues that will have to be addressed.  Your Windows 10 license was based on your hardware, in order to activate the installation within a VM on a different host, you would need to supply a new license as the old one cannot be transfered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Disk2VHD](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) tool to convert your laptop hard disk into a vm machine. Try that link and let us know.

Answer (score -1):

You can use clonezilla bootable iso to make an image of the hard-disk. create a virtual machine in virtual box . Boot into the virtual machine with clonezilla . The restore the image onto the virtual machine and you will have a virtual hard disk with the image of the previous hard disk.Close the virtual machine.  Then create a new virtual machine and attatch the virtual harddisk you  created from the previous steps and it should boot.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-use-clonezilla-to-clone-a-hard-drive/ this is a tutorial on clonezilla to get you started